# Submitting form to the Current page not working if the page has get vars

Tags: php, html, forms, smarty

I am using `action=""` so that my form submits to the current page.

But if the page is say `localhost/tnt/main1.php?display=signup` it won't submit correctly as my php script picks up the `?display=signup` and displays the blank form.
Any way to stop this?

EDIT:
I am using a smarty template that is used on multiple pages so action="main1.php" will not work for me.
The form is a POST form.

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but wouldn't action="main1.php" solve this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to submit it by POST or GET?

Comment: If possible, use seperate pages to do this.

Comment: Just edited my post,
And no given the system I am working with it has to be the same page.

Comment: Why, because you have the same form inside all your pages?

Comment: @Fred -ii- No, The setup I have has all the logic in 1 file and uses templates, due to a new requirement I set it up to have 3 pages which just include the system with a different db connection. 
Not optimal but don't have time to make it nicer.

Comment: Can you post what your form looks like in the tpl? Also would need to the relevant part of the PHP file.

Comment: How about `action="{$SCRIPT_NAME}"` ?

Answer (score 0):

put this in instead action="$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']"

Comment: "The requested URL /tnt/$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] was not found on this server." was the result.
Think its because its in the template file.

Comment: @marty987 that syntax is wrong.  If it's inside php scope you need to escape the double quotes.  If it's outside the scope you need to write it like this - action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"

Comment: @MrVimes that also failed, it navigated to http://localhost/tnt/%3C?php%20echo%20$_SERVER[%27PHP_SELF%27];%20?%3E

Comment: Is any other PHP code on the page working?  And is your form inside our outside PHP scope (the '<?php' and '?>' tags )

Comment: @MrVimes The form is in a Smarty template, so outside of PHP scope and there is no other PHP in the template. I am thinking smarty might escape the PHP.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I didn't realize at first that it was a template. That goes beyond my knowledge.  But under normal php circumstances my syntax for icluding the current document's name in the method paramater should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the responses,
I just hacked together a quick fix.
Used 3 directory's with index file in them.
Bad but I dint have time for a better fix.